# How to hide the file download with splash screen activity

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I am trying to implement an app in which I have to initially download a file, and only then can I proceed.  So I don't want to make the screen idle for N number of seconds for the **duration of downloads, I want to cover it with a splash screen**. So basically downloading all the files, and it will be covered by the splash activity.

This is the code I generally use for splash activity, then jumping to the main activity after the delay.

The real problem is that I have the AsyncTask in the main_activity, I want to show the splash screen, while I can download the file in the AsyncTask . Then I can move to the main activity

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity



                Intent i = new Intent(Splash_Screen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: What do you know about how the Android ui framework functions?

Comment: you mean to say ! that my kind of question is wrong ? or ..

Comment: No, I am asking your background so others or I know how detailed to make an answer.  You provide very little details in your question.

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh : Have you tried anything so far? If so, post your code and explain what your problems are.

Comment: you can consider me as an intermediate level programmer

Comment: This sounds like a job for a ProgressBar.

Comment: @Squonk: I know how to implement a splash screen .. but this kind of problem i have never faced before

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh It's not a matter of programming level, it seems quite a basic question yours, how would you do it? Any code?

Comment: i know how to make a splash screen work .. but this thing nope no idea ..

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh so if you know how to make a splash screen appear, what is the real question?  Do you not know how to download a file, or observe the file download status?

Comment: i'll update the question details in a clear manner

Answer (score 0):

I recommande you to choose the **AsyncTask**, where you can do a task in the backGround in your example downloading the file, and in the post execution wich mean after your file is downloaded you can do what ever you want.

```
private class Asyn_DownLoadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //download your file here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        /*this function is called automatically by the doInBackground when 
                    it finish it's work*/
    }

}
```

Just remenber AsyncTask must be subClassed, that's mean call implement the AsyncTask in the Splash screen Activity and in the onPostExecution do what you want

to start the AsyncTask use

```
 new Asyn_DownLoadFile().execute(null,null,null);
```

**EDIT:**

here what you have to do:

suppose this your **Splash** class

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    context = this;
    //.......................
    new Asyn_DownLoadFile().execute(null,null,null);
}

    //this is your function that downLoad the file
public void downLoadFile(){
     //............................
}

private class Asyn_DownLoadFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       downLoadFile();
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       Intent i = new Intent (context, MainActivity.class)
       startActivity(i);
   }

}

}
```

Comment: i have this AsyncTask in the main activity, and i have a splash screen now , so how can i display the splash screen ,while downloading the file and go the main activity

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh show the splash screen onPreExecute and hide it onPostExecute.

Comment: see mu edit please, i suppose that the SplashActivity is the Activity of your splash @VamsiPavanMahesh